# no rails file in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rubygems, rvm

I've accidentally removed rails file from `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin` (because it had old version of ruby in it) and now can't run any commands with rails. I have tried reinstalling rvm - `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` ruby - `rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.0` and rails - `gem install rails`, but nothing happens. What can I do to solve this?
Also for which ruby output is - `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby` but for rails it's empty

**UPD** Finally it works! I `rm -rf`ed my `~/.rvm` and reinstalled all from scratch, now it works.

Comment: have you a reloaded shell? or try `rvm reload` in current one

Comment: ok, where have you get the error?

Comment: I got this error when i deleted file ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rails cause it had old version of ruby in it (1.9.3 which I've deleted after upgrade to 2.1.0) and now I don't know how to create new one.

Comment: remove **Gemfile.lock** in your rails app, and issue: `bundle install` again, but before it show: `bundle  show ruby -v`

Comment: Unknown switches '-v'

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock also does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be enough to run:

```
rvm gemset pristine
```